# Is there any command that gets triggered on change in git branch?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

For example when we alter a document `vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument` gets triggered or when we go from one file to another `vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor` gets triggered. Is there any command that gets triggered or any way to figure out whether the branch has been changed?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout

Answer (score 1):

See [the git extension API type definitions file](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/be68a4e14c28cc81cdf422739af23123b3c91fd2/extensions/git/src/api/git.d.ts).

This API point in particular looks relevant to what you are looking for:

```js
export interface RepositoryState {
    readonly HEAD: Branch | undefined;
    readonly refs: Ref[];
    readonly remotes: Remote[];
    readonly submodules: Submodule[];
    readonly rebaseCommit: Commit | undefined;

    readonly mergeChanges: Change[];
    readonly indexChanges: Change[];
    readonly workingTreeChanges: Change[];

    readonly onDidChange: Event<void>;
}
```

This isn't a full answer, but please edit it or create one if you know how to complete it.